# Azure Pipeline variable instead of variable in powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a powershell script that creates a resource group and at the start I use the variable $rgname = "" to define the resource group name.

If I create a pipeline in Azure Devops that deploys that script it works fine but what I want to do is instead of defining the variable in the script I want to use the pipeline variable or a library variable group but I don't know how to define the variable in the script.

Everything I try ends in failure.

I want to use Azure Devops more and more and this would help me if I understand how to do this.

Comment: Could you add the failures that you are seeing in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create variables in two ways. Either by using the variables tab, or you can use the command `##vso[task.setvariable variable=<variable_name>]<variable_value>`. You can then reference that variable by using `$($<variable_name>)` e.g. in Powershell

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar]myVarValue"
Write-Host "The value of myVar is $($myVar)"
```

And your output would be

```
The value of myVar is myVarValue
```

The docs [here][1] have more information.
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: This does not work for me - i get the error: `myVar : The term 'myVar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: My mistake, my answer was missing the $ inside the brackets. I've edited my answer. The correct format is $($myVar)